# Jenkins is getting build automatically twice likely because of GIT Scm polling

Tags: docker, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

**Problem Statement:** Jenkins is getting an automatic build when only one build is pushed.

**Project Setup:** What I am trying to achieve is `Jenkins-Github` CI/CD setup. A simple `Flask` application is built and the same is pushed to `Github` test branch first. The repository has a webhook setup so that whenever a push event is detected a `POST` request to the Jenkins URL - this part is working fine. In Jenkins I have a simple Pipeline where I have the `Github` project configured and for Build option chose "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling". The pipeline setup is shown below. The pipeline (scripted) is also very simple -

1. builds a docker image of the flask application
2. performs few unit tests on the application
3. pushes the docker image to docker hub
4. pushes the code to master branch
5. sends notification.

**What is happening that I observed:** Once the `github` push is triggered and `Jenkins` build starts running which is expected but as soon as the 4th `stage` is reached observed that another `Jenkins` build is automatically started which I think is because of the `webhook` setup.

Now, I might be absolutely wrong as this is my first try (POC sort of) at Jenkins and also to be fair I was not very sure if I am doing/trying the right thing and also if this is the correct method to do such things. So, I would highly appreciate if I am being corrected here or atleast provided a correct approach. Please let me know if more information (script/code etc..) is required - thanks in advance.

Code used at scripted `pipeline` for pushing to master branch from test branch -

```
sh """git remote set-url origin git@github.com:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/FlaskApp.git
                          git checkout test
                          git pull
                          git checkout master
                          git pull origin master
                          git merge test
                          git status
                          git push origin master
                       """
```

[image: pipeline setup]

**Edit**:
Screen-grab of `github webhook` configuration-
[image]

**Environment:** Jenkins 2.249.1

Comment: I think it's because of the branch filter regex. Can you try changing that to ^test.* ?

Comment: Try what @PankajSaini has said. If it does not work, past the `event triggers` in GitHub side. It is possible that the job is getting triggered for two `events` i.e., once for `commit` and once for `push` .  Have you setup any SCM Timer Triggers on Jenkins side job configuration?

Comment: @PankajSaini - thank you, but specifying that(^test.*) as the "branch specifier" didn't help. Same story.

Comment: @mdabdullah - The jenkins build is getting triggered by two events, one for the push on "test" branch and the other for the push (I guess it has to be push as that's the only event that I have enabled to trigger) on "master" branch. I can confirm that when I see the recent webhook deliveries. 
Also, there are no SCM Timer Triggers only GITScm polling

Comment: Okay, and if you look in Console output of each job are you able to see the same `commit id` available in both?

Comment: @mdabdullah -  I didn't find any `commitid` in the console output but looked into the status and found that for the first build we have the commit information (changes, commit id, revision etc) and on the second build there are no commit information just revision.

Comment: Ok, at the beginnging of the console out put do you see any of these "Started by SCM change" , "Started by Timer" , "Started by Abhishek" . You need to figure what the trigger was, for each of the builds. It is not technical issue, it sounds like some configuration which has been setup by mistake.

Comment: @mdabdullah - Yes both the builds have the same "Started by GitHub push by iamabhishekchakraborty" which I had mentioned earlier both the builds are triggered by Github push.

I was looking into the Jenkinsfile and if and when I comment out the step/piece(which pushes code from test to master branch) the build would run only once.

Comment: Can you improve your posted question by adding screenshots of GitHub screens where you have configured the `trigger events` ?

Comment: @mdabdullah - edited, please refer above.

Comment: Can you make these two textboxes "Name" and "Refspec" empty and try again? I think the values `origin` and `+ref/heads..../test` may not be required.